# Multi-class classification with binary decision tree

Tags: machine-learning

I've built a decision tree for multi-class classification (MNIST).
My question is, whenever I want to predict the label of a test pattern and I follow the tree depending on the values of the test pattern's attributes, what happens if there is not a left or right branch for a given test pattern attribute value?
In tree building process I add branches on the left OR right depending on the training pattern attribute value I'm testing against a threshold.

Comment: no more splits -> leaf node -> assign label to test instance -> compare actual digit with predicted by tree

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if there is not a left or right branch for a given test
>   pattern attribute value?

This can only be the case if the instance arrives in a leaf node of the tree, in which case no further traversal of it is necessary and we classify the instance based on the class-conditional probability of the instance resulting from the class proportions in this node.
If the current node is **not** a leaf, the split operator is true for the given attribute value either on the right or the left, as for this purpose only $\geq$ (greater-or-equal) and $\leq$ (less-or-queal) are used.

Consider the example below, taken from page 306 of (1):
 a two-dimensional data set is iteratively split by thresholds as shown in the top right plot, starting at $X_1$ where the first threshold $t_1$ is defined. In the plot on the bottom left we see the corresponding tree structure, where the first split is representing the top node $X_1 \leq t_1$. Any given $x_1 \in X_1$ is either less-or-equal than $t_1$, in which case it continues on the left, or greater than $t_1$, in which case it continues on the right. There is no middle ground here.

[image]

> (1) Friedman, Jerome, Trevor Hastie, and Robert Tibshirani. The
>   elements of statistical learning. Vol. 1. No. 10. New York: Springer
>   series in statistics, 2001.

Comment: I found out the algorith for binary classification. Can you point me to the mult-class case?

Comment: What is unclear to you about the multiclass case? In a given leaf node, one uses the proportions of instances per clas that arrive there as estimates of the class-conditional probability - how one *decides* based on these is another matter entirely. For simple cases it might be enough assigning the class with the highest probability, while for more complex problems this might be suboptimal.